# Android - Java Parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, for-loop

I'm trying to parse a JSON response and pass the data to list view adapter.

This have worked:

```
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
      try {

       JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

       for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

               ..........
```

But this haven't:

```
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
      try {

       JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

       for (int i = feedArray.length(); i > 1; i--) {
         JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

               ..........
```

I need to parse the items from last to first, what I'm missing ? It's supposed to be an easy for statement but I've been trying for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
for (int i = feedArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Remember that lists start from 0 and end at (length-1).